# HTML File won't link to my CSS File

Tags: html, css, external

Is there anything I'm doing wrong I think I must have checked the code at least 1,000 times! I even Validated it to see if I missed anything.  Both HTML File and CSS file are in the same folder and named appropriately

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <!-- Zlimoli -->
     <title> Zlimoli Project </title>
     <meta name="description" content="type the content description here" />
     <meta name="keywords" content="type, keywords, here" />
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="music.css" type="text/css" />
     <style type="text/css">
     </style>
 </head>
```

It's Ethier that I won't link or my CSS code is wrong because it won't work.

CSS Code:

```
p.color1 {color: lime;}
h1.align {text-align: center;}
<!-- Zlimoli Project -->
```

And this is what it looks like when I apply it:

```
<h1 class="align"> Zlimoli Project </h1>
<p class="color1"> Sample Text Here </p>
```

Comment: http://test-cases.dorward.me.uk/stackoverflow/41781017/ — I can't reproduce the problem

Comment: `<!-- Zlimoli Project -->` is not a valid CSS comment. `/* Zlimoli Project */` would be correct.

Comment: what url are you browsing? `href="music.css"` is a relative path.

Answer (score 0):

You have written `<style>` tag wrong, try removing style tag.

```
> <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <!-- Zlimoli -->
     <title> Zlimoli Project </title>
     <meta name="description" content="type the content description here" />
     <meta name="keywords" content="type, keywords, here" />
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="music.css" type="text/css" />

 </head>
```